# Passing data from activity to interface

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, parameter-passing, retrofit

I'm trying to pass my data from one activity to an interface in kotlin. This value have to compose an url for getting a request json. Is it possible? How can I do it?

I'm new in app development and I never used interfaces before.

```
package com.example.adamo3.Request

import com.example.adamo3.Response.ExchangeResponse
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface RequestApi {
    @GET("statistiche/09050905")
     fun getAllPosts(): Call<ExchangeResponse>
 }
```

My target is to modify this url "statistiche/09050905", by changing the "09050905" to a parameter that I created in one activity. In this way, i will change the url to call from my server.

UPDATE
1) I have tried to insert

```
interface RequestApi {
@GET("statistiche/{id}")
fun getAllPosts(@Query("id") id: String ): Call<ExchangeResponse>
}
```

but when i do this, i receive error when i call the getAllPosts from a class(this one)

```
 private val retrofit = 
 Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
 private val postApi=retrofit.create(RequestApi::class.java)
 private val response = postApi.getAllPosts()// i receive error here
```

2) For retrieving the value that I need, in other classes I use

```
// receiving class
textView.text = intent.getStringExtra("Username")

// sending class
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,Home::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Username" ,"ID  " + editText.text.toString())
            startActivity(intent)
```

Where I need to define this part into the interface code suggested me?I need the value inside the editText arriving in the interface

3)
where I need to define the string with the intent? If I do it in the interface, "Property initializers are not allowed in interfaces"

```
interface RequestApi {
@GET("statistiche/{id}")
fun getAllPosts(@Query("id") id: String ): Call<ExchangeResponse>

String id = intent.getStringExtra("Username")//these two ways are errors
var id = intent.getStringExtra("Username")//same error

}
```

I want to receive values inside the interface

4) if I add the id here, it remains red as an error

```
private val response = postApi.getAllPosts(id)//id is red
```

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface RequestApi {
    @GET("statistiche/{id}")
     fun getAllPosts(@Query("id") id:String): Call<ExchangeResponse>
 }
```

Usage:

```
// receiving class
String id = intent.getStringExtra("Username")

private val retrofit = 
 Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
 private val postApi=retrofit.create(RequestApi::class.java)
 private val response = postApi.getAllPosts(id) // pass id here
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Birju. When I add this code I receive error when I call getAllPosts and I didn't understand where I need to insert the parameter that I receive from the other class. I will update my question to add the code for explaining these 2 problems.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I continue to receive errors, i will update my question for a better understanding

Comment: Yeah...you can mark it correct it solves what you had asked.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to running it yet, I still need your help please